# Alternative way of expressing the limit of a function

Tags: limits, derivatives

When proving that the limit

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x) $$

as $h \to 0$, am I correct in assuming that the limit

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} $$

as $h \to 0$ is equal to $f'(x)$? If so, why?

Fixed: Put the wrong fraction in the original question. Reversed the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, we have $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.$$ Now, let's make the substitution $k=-h,$ and observe that $h\to 0$ precisely as $k\to 0,$ so that $$f'(x)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x-k)-f(x)}{-k}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-k)}{k}.$$ Look familiar?

Comment: Thank you. I already did the numerator rewrite but the second fraction created by that is the one mentioned in the question. The first one is the exact definition of f'(x) but in the second one the signs are reversed.

Edit: I'm sorry but I messed up the question and put the wrong fraction in the original post :/

Comment: Answer corrected accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again, hadn't thought about using the substitution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x)$ exists then the limits both exist and are equal. However, it is possible that the top limit exists but $f'(x)$ does not exist. For example, take $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$.
Then $f(0+h)-f(0-h)=0$ for all $h$ so the limit is $0$. However, $f'(x)$ does not exist due to oscillations at $0$.